# Using Laplace transform solve the following differential equation : $ y'+y = 2 + \delta(t-4)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Using Laplace transform solve the following differential equation :
> $$ y'+y = 2 + \delta(t-4)$$, $$y(0)=0$$
> Express the solution $y(t)$ as a piecewise function about $t=4$ and tell us what happens to the graph of it at $t=4$.

**My try :**
Taking Laplace transform on the both sides :
$$ \big( s \cdot Y(s) - y(0) \big) + Y(s) = \frac{2}{s} + e^{-4s} \\
 \implies Y(s) = \frac{2}{s(s+1)} + \frac{e^{-4s}}{(s+1)} \\
\implies Y(s) = 2\Big(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+1}\Big) + \frac{e^{-4s}}{(s+1)}
$$
Now I'm stuck here because I dont know how to take the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{e^{-4s}}{(s+1)}$ . I haven't ever dealt with something involving exponential function. Can I get some help here please?

Comment: It integrates into a step function (or Heavyside function) that bumps up one unit at $t = 4.$   It would be written as $u(t-4)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:
$$\mathcal {L}^{-1}\{e^{-cs}F(s)\}=u(t-c)f(t-c)$$
You have a Laplace transform table [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. I've found the formula just now and ended up with $y(t) = 2(1-e^{-t}) + u_4(t) e^{4-t}$. But I don't know what is the definition of the unit step funtion at $t=4$. Is $u_4(t)$ just $u(t-4)$? @user577215664

Comment: Yes this  is correct @Itachi it's $u(t-4)$

Comment: Thanks. Can you quickly check if my solution is correct?

Comment: Your answerr looks correct to me @Itachi Well done

Comment: Alright!! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome @Itachi

Comment: Can you tell me wha should I write about the part "what happens to the graph of $y(t)$ at $t=4$"? I just see there's a jump discontinuity.

Comment: For $t<4$ you have that $u(t-4)e^{-(t-4)}=0$ @Itachi  and for $t>4$ you have $u(t-4)e^{-(t-4)}=e^{-(t-4)}$

Comment: Yes I noticed that. I split the funtion at $t=4$ but what should I write about the part "what happens to the graph of $y(t)$ at $t=4$"?

Comment: Take a look here https://math.mit.edu/~stoopn/18.031/stepanddelta.pdf  @Itachi  "We do not define u(t) at t = 0. Rather, at t = 0 we think of it as in transition
between 0 and 1"

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\mathcal {L}^{-1}\{e^{-cs}F(s)\}=u(t-c)f(t-c)$$ and

$$\mathcal {L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s+a}\right\}=e^{-at}u(t)$$ as your can see in [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).